Select closest geolocation insteado first result
I am curently developing a progressive web app for a school project. The pwa in essence does the following:
1: when it starts a list of rides from a theme park calledthe Eftelingare loaded and shown with a button to play audio from that rides pre-show. If there are more than one than multiple buttons will show .
2: If the user presses the button the audio file linked to that  button will be played. Aditionally a card willbe shown displaying both the ride selected and the specific audio file playing.
3: There is a also a button at the top of the screen alowingthe user to download all audio files to the cahh. This way the pwa also works without a internet connection(which is needed in the themepark sincethe internet there is not exactly stable).
4: If the user is within a (curently) 20 meter radius of a pre-show/ride the corinsponding audio will automatically play without further input from the user.
This last feature is what I am strugling with. The audio does play when within a 20 meter radius of a ride pre-show but the problem arises when there are multiple pre-shows for one atraction. This is becouse with my curent code the for loop wil go through all the rides until it finds coordinates that match with the 20 meter radius. However this also means that the first result in the list will be selected and not the closest coordinates. I am strugling to think of a simple way to work around this.
My curent code for both the coordinate radius calculation and selecting the correct audio files looks as as follows:
// Function to calculate distance between two coordinates
export function calculateDistance(userCoords, rideCoords) {
  const R = 6371e3; // metres
  const userLatRadians = (userCoords[0] * Math.PI) / 180;
  const rideLatRadians = (rideCoords[0] * Math.PI) / 180;
  const userLongRadians = (userCoords[1] * Math.PI) / 180;
  const rideLongRadians = (rideCoords[1] * Math.PI) / 180;
  const deltaLatitude = rideLatRadians - userLatRadians;
  const deltaLongitude = rideLongRadians - userLongRadians;

  const a =
    Math.sin(deltaLatitude / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLatitude / 2) +
    Math.cos(userLatRadians) *
      Math.cos(rideLatRadians) *
      Math.sin(deltaLongitude / 2) *
      Math.sin(deltaLongitude / 2);
  const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

  const distance = R * c;
  return distance;
}

// Function to check if user is within 20 meters of any ride
export function isNearAnyRide(userCoords, rides) {
  for (let ride of rides) {
    for (let coordinate of ride.coordinates) {
      let rideCoords = coordinate.coordinates.split(", ").map(Number);
      if (calculateDistance(userCoords, rideCoords) <= 20) {
        playAudio(ride.fileName, coordinate.name, true);
        console.log(`You are near ${ride.name}!`);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("You are not near any rides.");
  return false;
}

My question is if there is a way to ensure that not the first withing the 20 meter result but the closest result to the users coordinates(asuming it is within that 20 meter radius) will be selected. The easiest thing I can think of is putting the results that are within the 20 meter radius in a aray and run that through yet a other function that checks which one is closest to the user coordinates. But this to me feels confeluded and redundant.
